# Create edges from vertices and just faces alone

Tags: javascript, graphics, 3d

I need to try and workout the edges uses in an OBJ file, now a OBJ file doesn't include edges, so using just the vertices and faces alone, I need to create edges to fit with my model structure.

How can I create an edge using just the faces?

snippet of vertex data

```
v  1.6946 0.0000 -39.7987 //V1
v  8.5498 6.3593 -32.5369 //V2
v  10.1957 0.0000 -38.6795 //V3
v  1.6946 6.3593 -33.4394 //V4
v  6.9039 -0.0000 -26.3943 //V5
```

snippet of face data

```
f 1 2 3 
f 1 4 2 
f 4 5 2 
f 4 6 5
```

so face 1 is made up of vertex 1, 2 and 3
should I just create edge that is, 1 to 2, 2 to 3 and 3 to 1?

Answer (score 0):

You're correct.  Face 1 would be (v1,v2,v3) and face 2 would be (v2,v3,v4), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, creating an edge from 1 to 2, 2 to 3, and 3 to 1 for each of your faces will give you all of the edges in your object. Do note that there might (and probably will be) duplicates of some of the edges, when they are used in more than one face.

Comment: I don't think that will matter, as im just trying to stick the model into my structure so i can use my method on it :)

Answer (score 0):

I found out what to do, i took the first two vertices and then did a for loop to check to see if they were the edge array i made, if not then just push them onto the array, if they are then dont, and tell my face structure to take the for loop "i" value like so

```
var tempVer1 = faces[i][0];
            var tempVer2 = faces[i][1];

            tempEdge1 = tempEdges.length;
            var change = false;
            for(k=0;k<tempEdges.length;k++)
            {
                if(tempEdges[k][0] == tempVer1 && tempEdges[k][1] == tempVer2) 
                    {
                    change = true;
                    tempEdge1 = k;
                    }
                    else if(tempEdges[k][0] == tempVer2 && tempEdges[k][1] == tempVer1)
                    {
                    change = true;
                    tempEdge1 = -k;
                    }
            }
```

Hope this helps anyone else that need it :)